# Powershell - can I avoid typing .\ if I want to execute something from the current folder?

Tags: powershell, path

I'm trying to switch from cmd.exe to Powershell, but I'm very annoyed by the fact that if I try to execute something from the current folder, I have to type .\ before it, just like in Linux. Is there a way to disable this without adding the current folder or . to PATH?

Comment: There's really good security reasons that ".\" isn't in the path by default anymore. You should consider how rarely you want to run a program from the current directory before enabling this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using tab complete, type the first few letters and press tab. It will automatically prepend `.\` and if you keep pressing tab, it will keep suggesting the file name you need until you get to it (if there's more than 1 similar file name).

Comment: +1, Less keystrokes yet!

Comment: There are also some nice 3rd party tab completion things that may make this interaction nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Just like Linux, you'll have to add ".\" to your path. Powershell doesn't have a way to say, "automatically prepend .\ to %PATH%." The path statement will have to be modified.